# delete from non mapped objects hibernate and spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i'm trying to delete a user from database, but the problem is that the table user and table role are attached to a table called user_role, this table however doesn't have it's own class because it's created like this :

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

so in order to delete the user i need to delete it from the table user_role ,now when i try to do that with this function

```
@Query("delete from user_role r where r.user_id = :userid")
 void deleteUserRole(@Param("userid") long id);
```

i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: user_role is not mapped [delete from user_role r where r.user_id = :userid]
```

any suggestion to fix this is much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: maybe use a preparedStatement

Comment: @ScaryWombat how? i've never used preparedStatement with spring

Comment: well try something and see where you get stuck

Comment: Use manyToOne and OneToMany instead of ManyToMany, that way you would be able to refer to your middle table that you can't refer to now.

Comment: thanks everyone , i used preparedStatement and it worked!

Comment: No need to thank, just do vote up.